# Javascript Garbage Collection and encapsulated variables

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Based on the following way of encapsulating the variable `productId`, are calls to `ProductId.get()` guaranteed to return the previously set value or could the value have potentially been garbage collected and therefore be undefined?

```
var ProductId = (function () {
    var productId = -1;
    return {
        get: function () {
            return productId;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            productId = parseInt(val, 10);
        }
    };
})();
```

If for example I call `ProductId.set(1234)` and then, some time later, call `ProductId.get()`, could it have been GC? 
It seems, though I'm not 100% sure, that there is no, direct reference to the encapsulated variable productId and therefore it will be GC.

Comment: I'm sure that it won't get GC'd, because a call to `ProductId.get()` is in the code and can be called in some point in time.

Answer (score 1):

productId will be accessible in any time of script usage, it's classical example of closures, get and set methods will still have access to productId variable even after anonymous function will be executed.

Comment: This is what I initially thought (and in fact based much of my data encapsulation around) but I'm finding that a variable's value is being unexpectedly reset.
If what you said is correct I guess the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: i would suggest to describe your private variable in classical way to ensure that nothing affecting it: `var ProductId = (function () {
    this.productId = -1;
    return {
        get: function () {
            return this.productId;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            this.productId = parseInt(val, 10);
        }
    };
})();`

Comment: @WarrenGrimskin The default scope of an IIFE is window so in your case `productId` will be added to `window` (global).